# Modal content UX

Tags: web-app, tables, desktop-application, browser, modal

I have a situation where I need to display a table with multiple rows of data. Row count can be from 1 to 99. Is a scrollable modal the correct UX, or should I display this info on its own page?

Comment: Do you have mocks of your efforts so far? What is the larger context here?

Comment: As Mike says, I think the larger context is key here: how are users coming to the table, what are they using it for, and where are they going afterwards? Without know at least these three things no-one will be able to give you a sensible answer.

Comment: Long story short, the user uploads a spreadsheet file into a database, the file is checked for validation, if there are any errors the user needs to see which rows failed and the reason (validation rule) why it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I steer away from tables in modals/lightboxes

Tables this large would almost certainly be handled in-page as you are likely to need to perform actions on elements in the table (create/delete/edit etc) and having a table in a modal (or slide-out/lightbox) would lead to horrible interactions down the line

edit: just saw your comment

I did an interaction like this where it was done in-page. It was much easier to manipulate/view the spreadsheet data when the user wasn't constrained by smaller windows.